# Login with Email Identity Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I want to be able to log into my website with an email, but it appears as if Identity is set up so that the signInManager accepts usernames not emails to log in. I've seen posts where they use `FindByEmail()` to get the username and then pass that in, but when I try to use it I get a red squiggly saying that

> "UserManager< IdentityUser> does not contain a definition for 'FindByEmail' and no accessible extension method 'FindByEmail' accepting a first argument of type 'UserManager< IdentityUser>'"

I think it is because I am using Asp.Net Core not Asp.Net.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var signedUser = userManager.FindByEmail(model.Email);
                var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(signedUser, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {                    
                    return RedirectToPage("/Index");
                }                              
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid Email or Password");                
            }
            return View("Pages/Account/Login.cshtml", model);
        }
```

Comment: you can put the email in both username & email fields, then u can use for login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1?view=aspnetcore-3.1), there is no method `FindByEmail`. Only `FindByEmailAsync` exists. so, change your code to as below

`var signedUser = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);`